# How to send an email to myself on the same local machine (tcp port 25)

Tags: email, tcp, traffic

Does anyone know how to sent email to myself?
I am trying to generate TCP traffic on port 25.

Comment: Do you just want the email, or do you want to test an SMTP server on your machine?

Comment: You open up your favorite email program, fire up a new message editing window, put your email address in the "to"-field and you're good to go. Assuming your email program is configured correctly that will generate traffic on port 25 at least once on at least one host which goes beyond TCP connection requests. I think you need to put more effort into asking your question because the simple answer is "yes".

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to test if an smtp server works or to send some email by a shell script?

### [SWAKS](http://www.jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/) - Swiss Army Knife for SMTP

```
Swaks is a featureful, flexible, scriptable, transaction-oriented 
SMTP test tool written and maintained by John Jetmore. Features include:
* SMTP extensions including TLS, authentication, and pipelining
* Protocols including SMTP, ESMTP, and LMTP
* Transports including unix-domain sockets, internet-domain sockets 
  (IPv4 and IPv6), and pipes to spawned processes
* Completely scriptable configuration, with option specification 
  via environment variables, configuration files, and command line
```

Answer (score 1):

### telnet (to test out smtp protocol)

If you are trying to send email to yourself on the email server

```
telnet localhost 25
```

In this case you properly do not need to worry about correct HELO or login stuff, as email server generally will accept anything from localhost.

If you are trying to send email to yourself to an email server

```
telnet <email-server> 25
```

In this case depends on the configuration, the email server may reject your email if your box is not an email server(no mx record or spf record, etc).

Then follow this [Tutorial link](http://www.simplescripts.de/smtp-check-port-25-telnet-command.htm)

Comment: Instead of telnet, you can also use [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat).

Comment: @jofel True, it is almost identical in this usage.

Comment: yet you are not sending an email to anybody and calling an established TCP connection "generating traffic on port 25" is a little optimistic as well :-)

Comment: @user1129682 I included the tutorial link for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
# echo "This is message body" | mail -s "This is subject" you@domain.com
```

Or

```
# mail -s "My Subject" you@yourdomain.com < msg.txt
```

Comment: Originally I included this in my answer. However, after verifying the `mail.log`, the `mail` command seems to call mail queue directly, which bypass TCP/IP.

Comment: That's good to know. Hope that helps someone too. Thank you.